# How do I make LiveData appear?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am having a hard time getting my objects out of LiveData when I need them.

I have a room database giving me a LiveData<List> which I put into a recylcerview with an observer in onCreateView method of my fragment like so:

```
private LiveData<List<Card>> listCivicsLive;
listCivicsLive = mCivicViewModel.getAllCivics(sortingOrder);    
listCivicsLive.observe(requireActivity(), civics -> {
          adapter.submitList(civics);
          myItemKeyProvider.setItemList(civics);
          listCivics = civics;
    });
```

That part works fine. Whenever  the recylerview shows up, it is populated as I want it.
The problem start when I also want to put the same list into my ItemKeyProvider for my SelectionTracker.
I first tried to store the civics list provided by the observer above in a variable so I could use it in the constructor of the ItemKeyProvider. That always failed as it seems the observer is run a lot later then the tracker construction, so it always ended up in a NullPointerExeception from the getPosition method of the Provider, as I use the List there to calculate the item position. So I ended up constructing the Provider with a different lookup from the room db, where I used List instead of LiveData, which kinda works, but seems whacky. It ended in disaster later when I added a paramater the the room sql statement for sorting the list, because I seem to be unable to change the List I provide to the KeyProvider.

Anyway, to come back to my question I am trying to ask:

Is there a way to reliably pull the real data out of LiveData when I need it (tried .getValue() but that only ended in NullPointer Exceptions)?
Or am I forced to just mirror every sql query I have with LiveData and do another without it to get data when I want it?
At same point I thought .observe is it, until I realised that this is kinda async and fire at some point in time, but not in line of my other code.

Comment: `LiveData.getValue()` will return the current state of this `LiveData`. You get `NullPointerException` is because you tried to `getValue()` before the `LiveData` even emit its first value yet. As you said, it will take some time to query data from Room DB. This is like you declare a variable, and you use it before you initialize it. You will have to initialize your `ItemKeyProvider` inside `LiveData.observe()`, if it required the `civics` list in a constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but initializing the KeyProvder inside .observer() would also lead to putting the creation of the tracker there as well, as I would expect the same here; I can not do 
`tracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder()` where I need that KeyProvider as parameter.
So that would end up inside `LiverData.observer()` as well then I take it?:
`
myItemKeyProvider = new MyItemKeyProvider<String>(ItemKeyProvider.SCOPE_MAPPED, listCivics, mCivicViewModel);
tracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<>(...).build();
adapter.setSelectionTracker(tracker);
`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting up there, still learning to post here :-)

I was wondering now, if it would not be more convenient to just forget all about the LiveData aspect and just go for normal `List<Card>` objects instead. In the end, the data in the db will def. not change while I am on that fragment and only after one hits a button (which changes stuff, but also returns the user to another fragment). Where just following the "Room with a View" codelab while trying to find something for me that works.